# getting java.lang.NullPointerException while reading hudi table data using spark sql while calling in spark action

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, nullpointerexception, apache-hudi

I am getting weird pyspark java null pointer exception while calling any action through pyspark. below is the snippet for this:

py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o432.showString.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 28 in stage 13.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 28.3 in stage 13.0 (TID 3334) (172.34.78.50 executor 3): java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.UnsafeWriter.write(UnsafeWriter.java:110)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:755)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.columnar.DefaultCachedBatchSerializer$$anon$1.next(InMemoryRelation.scala:101)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.columnar.DefaultCachedBatchSerializer$$anon$1.next(InMemoryRelation.scala:93)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.next(Iterator.scala:455)
at org.apache.spark.storage.memory.MemoryStore.putIterator(MemoryStore.scala:222)
at org.apache.spark.storage.memory.MemoryStore.putIteratorAsBytes(MemoryStore.scala:349)
at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.$anonfun$doPutIterator$1(BlockManager.scala:1440)
at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.org$apache$spark$storage$BlockManager$$doPut(BlockManager.scala:1350)
at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doPutIterator(BlockManager.scala:1414)
at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.getOrElseUpdate(BlockManager.scala:1237)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.getOrCompute(RDD.scala:384)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:335)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
at org.apache.spark.shuffle.ShuffleWriteProcessor.write(ShuffleWriteProcessor.scala:59)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:99)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:52)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:131)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:497)
at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1439)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:500)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)

Below is the code we are using:

drop_cols = ['_hoodie_commit_time', '_hoodie_commit_seqno', '_hoodie_record_key', '_hoodie_partition_path',
'_hoodie_file_name', 'etl_datetime']

```
    qry = "select * from " + voc_db_name + "." + voc_table_name
    complete_data = spark.sql(qry)
    cnt_before_transformation = complete_data.count()
    logger.warning(
            "Record counts for {}.{} table before applying any transformation : {}".format(voc_db_name,
                                                                                           voc_table_name,
                                                                                           cnt_before_transformation))
    complete_business_data = complete_data.drop(*drop_cols)
        # Persist the DataFrame in memory
    complete_business_data.persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY)

    complete_business_data = complete_business_data.withColumn("store", expr(
        "CASE WHEN (upper(platform) == 'OS' AND store == '123_1') THEN '123A' " +
        "WHEN (upper(platform) == 'OS' AND store == '123_2') THEN '123B' " +
        "WHEN (upper(platform) == 'OS' AND store == '123_4') THEN '123C' " +
        "WHEN (upper(platform) == 'OS' AND store == '123_5') THEN '123D' " +
        "ELSE store END")) \
        .withColumn("hist_etl_runtime", expr(
        "CASE WHEN (upper(platform) == 'OS') THEN '1900-01-01 00:00:00' " +
        "ELSE hist_etl_runtime END")) \
        .withColumn("etl_datetime", from_utc_timestamp(current_timestamp(), 'Asia/Shanghai'))

    complete_business_data = complete_business_data.withColumn("hist_etl_runtime",
                                                                col("hist_etl_runtime").cast(TimestampType()))
    print("after data logic")
    complete_business_data.na.fill("nulltext")
    complete_business_data.na.fill(0)
    default_time = '1980-01-01 00:00:00'
    complete_business_data = complete_business_data.fillna({'review_created_time': default_time})
    complete_business_data = complete_business_data.fillna({'hist_etl_runtime': default_time})
    complete_business_data = complete_business_data.fillna({'pay_date': '1980-01-01'})
    complete_business_data = complete_business_data.fillna({'review_date': '1980-01-01'})
    complete_business_data = complete_business_data.fillna({'order_created_time': default_time})
    complete_business_data = complete_business_data.fillna({'start_time': '1980-01-01'})
    complete_business_data = complete_business_data.fillna({'end_time': '1980-01-01'})
    complete_business_data = complete_business_data.fillna({'target_date': '1980-01-01'})
    complete_business_data = complete_business_data.fillna({'insert_time': default_time})
    complete_business_data.dropna()
    complete_business_data.select([count(when(col(c).isNull(), c)).alias(c) for c in complete_business_data.columns]).show()
    cnt_after_transformation = complete_business_data.count()
```

As per my previous findings i have used df.na.fill() function to replace null values for string, long/int and timestamp columns. Also I have tried with df.dropna() but nothing worked with me.

I want to run this code to be executed without null pointer. And if there is any null in data then it should not fail

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Can you plz provide hudi version ?